# Calculate the inverse Laplace transform $\frac{s-2}{(s+1)^4}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to calculate the inverse Laplace transform of $$\frac{s-2}{(s+1)^4}$$

Not quite sure how to do this one. I see that you should break the numerator up into $$\frac{s}{(s+1)^4}-\frac{2}{(s+1)^4}$$.

But looking at my table of elementary inverse inverse laplace transforms I can't quite figure out how to manipulate the bottom to get a correct answer

Comment: Does your table of Laplace transforms mention the transform of $t^n e^{at}$?

Comment: No it does not include thst

Comment: Could I complete the square of a 4th power?

Comment: look at any course on the Laplace transform, and integrate by parts, and use latex

Comment: Hint: breaking up the numerator in the form $s-2=(s+1)-3$ is more useful

Comment: I see so I wojld be able to cancel one of the s+1

Comment: Then I am left with 1/(s+1)^3 and -3•1/(s+1)^4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we should find the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{(s+1)^4}$. If you look at a table of Laplace transforms, you'll see that
$$L(t^ne^{at}) = \frac{n!}{(s-a)^{n+1}}$$
(this formula can be shown by induction & integration by parts). So we can see that 
$$L(\frac{t^3e^{-t}}{3!}) = \frac{1}{(s+1)^4}$$

Most tables will also mention that
$$L(f'(t))(s) = s\cdot L(f(t)) - f(0)$$
And so we have 
$$L(3t^2e^{-t} - t^3e^{-t}) = L(\frac{d}{dt}t^3e^{-t}) = \frac{3!s}{(s+1)^4}$$
And so the inverse Laplace transform of our original function is

$$\frac{1}{3!}(3t^2e^{-t} - t^3e^{-t} - 2t^3e^{-t})$$

Comment: Ah yes I see, thanks  your answer conflicts with the answer given above

Comment: This answer is equivalent to the other one given (and the one given by Wolfram Alpha), I just didn't reduce it.

Comment: Yes it is just noticed   thanks for your time

Comment: So I figured I would have to use all my laplace inverse formulas but how come you used a laplace transform formula for 1/(s+4)^4

Comment: Because that expression appeared in the function we needed to take the inverse Laplace transform of? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I was just given a table for inverse laplaxe and a table for laplace transform  however that one was covered in the inverse laPlace but it was given in laplace transform  so that's why I was confused cause I thought I had to use the inverse laPlace like I did for the first part of the equation

Comment: Any formula used to calculate a Laplace transform can also be used to calculate inverse Laplace transforms, since $L(f(t))(s) = g(s)$ is the same as saying $L^{-1}(g(s))(t) = f(t)$.

Comment: Okay makes sense  thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that
>   $\ds{{s - 2 \over \pars{s + 1}^{4}} = {1 \over \pars{s + 1}^{3}} -
> {3 \over \pars{s + 1}^{4}}}$.

With $\ds{\ul{\sigma, \mu > 0}}$:
\begin{align}
\,\mathrm{f}\pars{\mu} & \equiv
\int_{\sigma - \infty\ic}^{\sigma + \infty\ic}{\expo{st} \over s + \mu}\,
{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} = \expo{-\mu t}
\end{align}

---

$$
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcccl}
\ds{\int_{\sigma - \infty\ic}^{\sigma + \infty\ic}
{\expo{st} \over \pars{s + 1}^{3}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\half\,\,\mathrm{f}''\pars{1}} &  \ds{=} & \ds{\half\,t^{2}\expo{-t}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\int_{\sigma - \infty\ic}^{\sigma + \infty\ic}
{\expo{st} \over \pars{s + 1}^{4}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{1 \over 6}\,\,\mathrm{f}'''\pars{1}} &  \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 6}\,t^{3}\expo{-t}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

$$
\color{#f00}{Solution}:\quad
\half\,t^{2}\expo{-t} - 3\pars{{1 \over 6}\,t^{3}\expo{-t}} =
\color{#f00}{\half\,t^{2}\pars{1 - t}\expo{-t}}
$$